# Linux - two devices writing to the same device node

Tags: linux, device, nodes, drivers, udev

Okay, I have two joysticks attached to my linux box and they show up as /dev/js0 and /dev/js1.  My problem is, I have a third party application, (that I cannot change), that uses a joystick, and it can only listen to one node, (so only one joystick at a time).
I can determine which node the application will "listen" to, (e.g. /dev/js0), but I can only specify one node. This means I can determine which joystick the application will use, but that also means it can only use one joystick at a time. 
I have been tasked to come up with a way that this application can use both joysticks at the same time in an either/or scenario and not one or the other.

Is there a way to redirect the outputs of the two joystick nodes into a third node to which I could then point the application?  Is there another way that comes to mind to somehow "merge" these two drivers/nodes into one?

I tried creating a new third node, (dev/js2) using mknod, but I couldn't figure out how to redirect the output of js0 and js1 to js2.

I'm also not opposed to doing this using a small program and udev, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/ is more suitable for this

Comment: im not sure if you should or even if it is possible to merge the two nodes into a third because they are specific to the device. and since there are two devices there should be two nodes.